# Quartz to define a mail, 12 hours after hitting after trigger aspx

Tags: asp.net, email, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I'm trying to add a functionality where you send a mail to 3 specific references 12 hours after hitting the button to send a mail to a contact (that part is already working). I'm using Quartz, but I do not know if this will work. The sendMailEveryone() is already working (but it is taking values off that specific page), but I want it to keep these values to be sent 12 hours (trying first for 10 minutes) after clicking the button.

Here is my code:

```
    void schedulerMail()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();
        IJobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.Create<sendMailEveryone>().Build();
        ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInMinutes(10))
    .Build();
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job1, trigger1);
    }

    protected void sendMailEveryone(ASF.HC.JobApplication.BO.Campo dbDatos) {
        String ref1Mail = dbDatos.GetKey("txtReference_mail1");
        String ref2Mail = dbDatos.GetKey("txtReference_mail2");
        String ref3Mail = dbDatos.GetKey("txtReference_mail3");
        String body = "linksssssssss";
        String title = "titulo del mail";
        BO.Messages mail = new BO.Messages();
        mail.refEmail(ref1Mail, title, body);
        mail.refEmail(ref2Mail, title, body);
        mail.refEmail(ref3Mail, title, body);

    }
```

Comment: save those values in database and fetch it when its time to send

Comment: Can't you store them in the JobDataMap? That's of course assuming that you're using a persistent JobStore.

Comment: as a matter of fact, theyre stored in the DB. What I want and try to do is figure out, how to send a simple mail in 10 minutes but all I do is fail :(

Comment: Create a windows service that is running in the background. That is much better.